# Junit in spring based project where multiple projects are involved

Tags: java, spring, junit, automated-tests

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="commonBean" class="commonBean">
    </bean>

</beans>

@Configuration
@ImportResource({
    "classpath:"commonConfig.xml"
    })
public class CommonBeanConfiguration{

}
```

We have a common project as above.We are using this as jar in another project(Main Project).
We are using commonBean bean from another project(Main Project).

When we deploy Main Project(including jar of common project) on server.It works fine.
But we get "commonBean not found exception" if we try to run junit classes from Main Project. seems like beans from commonConfig.xml is
not being created in junit.

we are using spring for testing.

```
RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:commonConfig.xml")
```

instead of `@import` as it loads the bean during runtime while `@ContextConfiguration` loads bean before invoking test cases.